# Cannot install SQL Server 2008 Management Studio - Need Visual Studio C++ 2008 SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

Having a really strange issue on a laptop (Windows 7 Home Premium, soon to be updated to Pro)

When i try to install Web Management Studio for SQL Server Express 2008.  Every time i try to load it i receive the following:

```
You must install Visual Studio C++ 2008 SP1
```

Now, i don't have Visual Studio 2008 installed on this machine, which would make the above make sense with regards to this message and its applied fixes that you can find on Google.  I have tried to install the distributables to try and overcome this problem but nothing has worked.

I did have 2010 express installed (now uninstalled), and now have 2012 but it is really becoming annoying.  Has anyone had the same issue, where VS2008 is not installed but you still get this and how the hell i can fix it.  The registry fixes don't work as i don't have the VS2008 entries to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clean up your registry to make sure you dont have any residual entry of previous installations.

Comment: Going to restore the machine to factory settings, Registry would be better but i have no idea what to look for.